# Error: Inline Babel script: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Tags: reactjs

I am using ReactJS, i am getting this error:

> Inline Babel script: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an
>   enclosing tag.

One more thing: Can I use multiple state in my component, how?

Here is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component (
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            header: "Header from state...",
            data:[]
        }

        this.setStateHandler = this.setStateHandler.bind(this);   
    } 
    setStateHandler() {
        var item = "ReactJs :)"
        var myArray = this.state.data;
        myArray.push(item)
        this.setState({data: myArray}) 
    };  
    render(){ 
        return(  
            <p>{this.state.header}</p>
            <button onClick = {this.setStateHandler}>SET STATE</button>
            <p>State Array: {this.state.data}</p>  
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: r u facing any issue, when using multiple states ??

Comment: unexpected token

Comment: saying multiple state makes no sense. you have an invalid render method. react can handle multiple state variables if thats what you're talking about.

Comment: Corrected the wording of you question, even if it seem unrelated to your problem after all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is in `return`, you are `returning` more than one `html element`, wrap them in a `div` it will work.

**Reason**: A `React` component can't `return` multiple elements, but a single `JSX` expression can have multiple children, so if you want a component to `render` multiple things you can wrap them in a div.

Don't forget that the `render()` is basically a `function`, Function always take in number of parameters and always `return` exactly one value.

Use this:

```
render(){ 
   return(  
     <div>
        <p>{this.state.header}</p>
        <button onClick = {this.setStateHandler}>SET STATE</button>
        <p>State Array: {this.state.data}</p>  
     </div>
   )
}
```

You need to change the way you are updating the state variable. **Never mutate state variable directly**. Instead of pushing the values directly into State variable array, first create a copy of that then update the value and push the data back into state. Like this:

```
let a = this.state.data.slice();
a.push('React');
this.setState({data: a});
```

> multiple State using in single component...?

You can declare many variable inside state object, but declaring state object multiple times doesn't make any sense.

Check the working example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            header: "Header from state...",
            data:[]
        };

        this.setStateHandler = this.setStateHandler.bind(this);   
    } 
    setStateHandler() {
        var item = "ReactJs :)"
        var myArray = this.state.data.slice();
        myArray.push(item);
        this.setState({data: myArray}) 
    };  
    render(){ 
        return(  
            <div>
               <p>{this.state.header}</p>
               <button onClick = {this.setStateHandler}>SET STATE</button>
               <p>State Array: {this.state.data}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```